# 18650 battery holder: SMT or THM for 15A?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

While looking for a **quality and high current (max 15A)** 18650 Lithium battery holder, I've found that Keystone offers:

- **Surface Mount** Style with contacts of stainless steel and "**gold flash over nickel plate**" finish;

  "Gold Flash for outstanding solder performance and low contact resistance" (source: Keystone)

  [image: SMT holder]
- **Through Hole** Style with contacts of stainless steel and "**tin nickel plate**" finish;

  "Tin over Nickel plate for superior soldering." (source: Keystone)

  [image: THM holder]

[Here](https://www.keyelco.com/category.cfm/Cylindrical-Cell-Holders/Holders-Plastic-PCB/p/404/id/1213/c_id/418) an overview from Keystone website.

I am not sure **which one to choose**:

1. The **pin of the Through Hole Version are about 1mm diameter, while the SMT version has 6x7mm pads**. So I wonder **if the Through Hole can carry more then 2-3A**. I've read in a forum of somebody getting 20-30A, but this is unverified.
2. The SMT version could be better for my case but it has **gold flash** finish contacts, which 18650 batteries usually don't. It is advised **not to  mix gold and tin contacts** due to the chemical reaction  over time that will deteriorate the electrical connection.

What's your experience or suggestion? Are my worries valid?

The description from Keystone don't help much and there is no mention of Current Rating or other electrical properties in the datasheets.

Comment: What are the actual ratings of the respective holders?   The current you are trying to draw is a bit atypical for that form factor.

Comment: Pretty sure none of those are meant for 15A

Comment: Even if they were, I've never seen a battery of those types that can deliver that much current.

Comment: @JYelton LiFe (A123) can. 1100mAh in that cell size and can deliver 12-15C continuously without heating up to result in significant reduction of charge cycles. Double that is their maximum so 30A.

Comment: @JYelton, There are many 18650 cells available that can deliver 15A. The ones used for power tools, "e-mobility"  and vaping can deliver very high currents.

Comment: Keystone does not provide current ratings for those holders as far as I can see. I suspect they will get very hot very fast with 15A going through them. You are going to want something made of nickel or a copper alloy, not steel or stainless steel. Or, if it is steel/stainless steel then the cross section of the conductor needs to be pretty large to carry 15A without over-heating.

Comment: One thing that works in your favor is that the cell cannot deliver 15A for very long. So continuous operation at 15A is physically impossible. For example a 3Ah cell discharging at 15A will lass less than 12 minutes.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: there are no current ratings mentioned in the datasheet: just catalog page and drawing (example: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/keystone-electronics/1043/36-1043-ND/ ).

Comment: @JYelton: for example "Samsung INR18650-30Q" 3000mAh has 5C 15A max discharge current

Comment: @mkeith Interesting. Most of the cells I use are LiSO2 for extremely long life (10 yr) and have pathetic maximum currents of hundreds of mA. I imagined other chemistries having easily 10X that, but not 100X or more.

Comment: @JYelton it was an eye-opener for me, too. https://www.samsungsdi.com/lithium-ion-battery/power-devices/power-tool.html

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I would not draw 15A continuously but maybe short peaks of 1 sec, average would probably be 10A.

Comment: what is the application? ... do you expect any intense vibration or mechanical shock?

Comment: @jsotola: it could be for a small outdoor robot or rover, some vibrations possible but nothing too big.